# Finding a type's instance data in .net heap

Tags: c#, .net, clrmd

Let's say I have two class Foo and Bar as follows

```
public class Foo
{
    private Bar _bar;
    private string _whatever = "whatever";
    public Foo()
    {
        _bar = new Bar();
    }

    public Bar TheBar
        {
            get
            {
                return _bar;
            }

        }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have an  application that attaches to a process that is using these classes. I would like to see all instances of Foo type in .NET heap and inspect the TheBar.Name property or _whatever field of all 
Foo instances present in .NET heap. I can find the type but I am not sure how to get the instance and see its properties. Any ideas how?

```
using (DataTarget target = DataTarget.AttachToProcess(processId, 30000))
{
    string dacLocation = target.ClrVersions[0].TryGetDacLocation();
    ClrRuntime runtime = target.CreateRuntime(dacLocation);

    if (runtime != null)
    {
        ClrHeap heap = runtime.GetHeap();
        foreach (ulong obj in heap.EnumerateObjects())
        {
            ClrType type = heap.GetObjectType(obj);
            if (type.Name.Compare("Foo") == 0 )
            {
                // I would like to see value of TheBar.Name property or _whatever field of all instances of Foo type in the heap. How can I do it?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get the fields, but I don't think you can get the properties because that is tantamount to calling a method in the attached process. I don't think CLR MD gives you the power to do this, since the target might not even be a process but a dump file.

Comment: can you show an example as to how can I get to fields? I have updated my question to either show property related data or field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can get property values directly because that would require you to run code and the target might not even be a process but a dump file.

You can definitely get an object's fields and their values. ClrType has a Fields property which you can use to loop through fields. Then you can call GetFieldValue for fields where HasSimpleValue is true.

A simple example:

```
private static void PrintFieldsForType(ClrRuntime runtime, string targetType)
{
    ClrHeap heap = runtime.GetHeap();
    foreach (var ptr in heap.EnumerateObjects())
    {
        ClrType type = heap.GetObjectType(ptr);
        if (type.Name == targetType)
        {
            foreach(var field in type.Fields)
            {
                if (field.HasSimpleValue)
                {
                    object value = field.GetFieldValue(ptr);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}) = {2}", field.Name, field.Type.Name, value);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", field.Name, field.Type.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So you could look for a field that has "Name", "_name", or something similar in it. If it is an auto-implemented property, the name will be something like `<Name>k__BackingField`.

Your scenario is a little more complicated in that you want to go into another object. To do that we can recursively inspect the fields. However note that in the general case you would want to keep track of which objects you've visited so you don't recurse indefinitely.

Here is an example that is more appropriate for this:

```
private static void PrintFieldsForType(ClrRuntime runtime, TextWriter writer, string targetType)
{
    ClrHeap heap = runtime.GetHeap();
    foreach (var ptr in heap.EnumerateObjects())
    {
        ClrType type = heap.GetObjectType(ptr);
        if (type.Name == targetType)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("{0}:", targetType);
            PrintFields(type, writer, ptr, 0);
        }
    }
}

private static void PrintFields(ClrType type, TextWriter writer, ulong ptr, int indentLevel)
{
    string indent = new string(' ', indentLevel * 4);
    foreach (var field in type.Fields)
    {
        writer.Write(indent);
        if (field.IsObjectReference() && field.Type.Name != "System.String")
        {
            writer.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", field.Name, field.Type.Name);
            ulong nextPtr = (ulong)field.GetFieldValue(ptr);
            PrintFields(field.Type, writer, nextPtr, indentLevel + 1);
        }
        else if (field.HasSimpleValue)
        {
            object value = field.GetFieldValue(ptr);
            writer.WriteLine("{0} ({1}) = {2}", field.Name, field.Type.Name, value);
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", field.Name, field.Type.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could do it in LINQPad with [ClrMD.Extensions](https://github.com/JeffCyr/ClrMD.Extensions):

```
var session = ClrMDSession.AttachToProcess(processId);
session.EnumerateClrObjects("*Foo").Dump(depth:3);
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if it's possible to query the heap in such a way . 
but an easy soluotion is to do something like this :

```
public class Foo
{
    public static List<WeakReference<Foo>> allInstances = new List<WeakReference<Foo>>();

    public Foo()
    {
        allInstances.Add(new WeakReference<Foo>(this));
    }
}
```

Make sure to wrap then in a WeakReference so your collection won't keep them in the heap until the process ends .

Comment: You probably are missing the point of my question. I think that's the whole purpose of clrmd library, to inspect runtime elements.

Comment: o'k but it seems like a lot to take in for something that can be easily done your self